# How to increase the default balance of Hardhat Anvil users?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I am using Anvil for some integration tests & am **occasionally** getting the error "Error: ran out of gas". I'm using 10 users, the first one as the deployer. The default balances for all the nodes is 10000000000000000000000. How can I increase this? Alternatively can I reduce the gas price?

### My Attempt

I'm using one user to fund other with their own balance. But this leads to the occasional out of gas error.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the default account balance with the `accountsBalance` and `balance` properties in your config.

```
networks: {
    hardhat: {
        // object for mnemonic-defined accounts
        // these are the default values if you didn't override
        accounts: {
            mnemonic: "test test test test test test test test test test test junk",
            accountsBalance: "10000000000000000000000",
        }
    }
}
```

```
networks: {
    hardhat: {
        // array for privatekey-defined accounts
        accounts: [privateKey: "0x...", balance: "10000000000000000000000"]
    }
}
```

Docs: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#accounts

---

However, the "out of gas" is a generic error similar to "Runtime Error" in other languages.

It's often caused by a failed `require` condition that produces an exception. And an uncaught exception causes revert of the transaction/call.

In some small amount of cases, it's also possible that your contract used up all of the `gas` units limit that you specified while sending the transaction. If you didn't specify any limit explicitly, your node (emulator) filled in an estimated value.

I'd suggest posting a separate question with repro steps.